# Laravel/Javascript Web Form Capture App

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a prototype build for a simple application that captures form data on a 3rd website and inserts it into mysql. So far, I have written the JS to capture dynamic form data and insert it into mysql as json.

I am using Laravel as my framework.

First of all, I am trying to understand how embedded code would work. I examined a software call What Coverts that has this feature. After doing some reason, it seems that they have a seperate js file for every project posted in their system. This js file is hosted on a seperate server. For example:

Application is hosted at app.whatconverts.com while their embed code shows their js file to be hosted at scripts.iconnode.com/59770.js. After examining the JS file, I found that they are posting to the same server as the js file.

Here are some questions:

Why did they and many other well know software like Hubspot choose this method?
Why are they creating these separate js files for every project?
How do they update the code in these js files?
These js files have dynamic variable that are being inserted from the database, are they connecting to the db through js?
Is there a better way to do this?

I am assuming that the reason they do it this way is because every website that uses this code is different and they have to use the most compatible method which will work across various hosting environments. Shorts answers will do. I am totally confused about this approach. I am new to javascript so I appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question is too global and vague at the moment. I'm sure they don't connect to the database using javascript as this is unsecure, they might make a call to the backend though. More details are required to give you a more advanced answer.

Comment: I just want to know why did they choose to use individual JS files for each company profile? why not use a simple id through url method?

Answer (score 0):

I used node.js, express.js and pug to resolve this. I am still working through these issues. Basically, you are able to use JS code and manipulate it through express.js routing. For my needs, this was sufficient.